# Mongodb Regex Query first 2 characters of the string

Tags: regex, mongodb

In one of my mongodb collection, I have a date string that has a mm/dd/yyyy format. Now, I want to query the 'mm' string.

Example, 05/20/2016 and 04/05/2015.

I want to get the first 2 characters of the string and query '05'. With that, the result I will get should only be 05/20/2016.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried adding this '/^[05]{2}/', where it will get all data with '05' on the first 2 strings. However, it seems it doesn't work. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong. Here's the code: {leaves_start: {$regex : '/^[05]{2}/'}}

Comment: What about this one then? `{leaves_start: {$regex : '/^05/'}}` It means that you want the leaves_start field to start with `05`.

Answer (score 8):

For a regex solution, the following will suffice

```
var search = "05",
    rgx = new RegExp("^"+search); // equivalent to var rgx = /^05/;

db.collection.find({ "leave_start": rgx });
```

**Testing**

```
var leave_start = "05/06/2016",
    test = leave_start.match(/^05/);
console.log(test); // ["05", index: 0, input: "05/06/2016"]
console.log(test[0]); // "05"
```

**or**

```
var search = "05",
    rgx = new RegExp("^"+search),
    leave_start = "05/12/2016";
var test = leave_start.match(rgx);
console.log(test); // ["05", index: 0, input: "05/06/2016"]
console.log(test[0]); // "05"
```

---

Another alternative is to use the aggregation framework and take advantage of the **[`$substr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/)** operator to extract the first 2 characters of a field and then the **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** operator will filter documents based on the new substring field above:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "leaves_start": 1,
            "monthSubstring": { "$substr": : [ "$leaves_start", 0, 2 ] }
        }
    },
    { "$match": { "monthSubstring": "05" } }
])
```

---